# Run custom Flask Click command with the app factory pattern

Tags: python, flask, command-line-interface, python-click

I am using the app factory pattern to create my Flask app and want to use it with the `flask` Click command. I found an [example](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2020#issuecomment-252455025) of how to do this by creating a custom `FlaskGroup` in the Flask issue tracker. However, it doesn't show how to use the new command. How do I run my custom Click command instead of the default `flask` one?

```
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup

cli = FlaskGroup(create_app=create_app)
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the top-level group, as [shown](http://click.pocoo.org/) on the front page of the Click docs:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()  # or cli.main()
```

You can also install an entry point from `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myapp=myapp:cli',
        ],
    },
    ...,
)
```

```
myapp run
```